# Update list of child items in data set using ng-repeat and index value passed from navigation

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have displayed a list of items in my data set using the ng-repeat as below.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in adults[1].children">
    {{item.childName}}
</li>
```

What I would like to do is HOW TO dynamically update the list using navigation such as this to show the other child items -

```
<li ng-click="updateList(1)">First kids</li>
<li ng-click="updateList(2)">Second group of kids</li>
<li ng-click="updateList(3)">Third group of kids</li>
```

**dataset**

```
  $http.get('data/parents-data.json')
    .then(function(res) {
        $scope.adults= res.data;
  });

  [
      {
        "parentName": "Jim",
        "age": "32",
        "sex": "M",
        "children": [
            {"childName": "Jennifer"},
            {"childName": "Timmy"}
        ]
      },
      {
        "parentName": "Barbara",
        "age": "29",
        "sex": "F",
        "children": [
            {"childName": "Oliver"},
            {"childName": "Henry"},
            {"childName": "Jane"}
        ]
      },
      {
        "parentName": "Sue",
        "age": "40",
        "sex": "F",
        "children": [
            {"childName": "William"},
            {"childName": "Robyn"},
            {"childName": "Sarah"}
        ]
      }
    ]
```

I'm really stumped as to how to get the updateList function to return the index back to the the ng-repeat

I tried

```
$scope.updateList = function(val) {
    return adults[x].children;
}
```

With

```
<li ng-repeat="item in updateList()>
{{item.childName}}
</li>
```

But this *obviously* didn't work. I just can't get this clear in my head. Maybe I'm doing this wrong. Any help at all greatly appreciated : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  just have to create a new `$scope` variable and update it on `ng-click` to change the list of childrens.

```
//Default set of children
 $scope.childrens=$scope.adults[0].children;

//Update childrens variable on click
 $scope.updateList = function(x) {
    $scope.childrens=$scope.adults[x].children;
}
```

```js
var app=angular.module("App",[]);
app.controller("AppCtrl",function($scope){
$scope.adults = [
      {
        "parentName": "Jim",
        "age": "32",
        "sex": "M",
        "children": [
            {"childName": "Jennifer"},
            {"childName": "Timmy"}
        ]
      },
      {
        "parentName": "Barbara",
        "age": "29",
        "sex": "F",
        "children": [
            {"childName": "Oliver"},
            {"childName": "Henry"},
            {"childName": "Jane"}
        ]
      },
      {
        "parentName": "Sue",
        "age": "40",
        "sex": "F",
        "children": [
            {"childName": "William"},
            {"childName": "Robyn"},
            {"childName": "Sarah"}
        ]
      }
    ];
    $scope.childrens=$scope.adults[0].children;
    $scope.updateList = function(x) {
     $scope.childrens=$scope.adults[x].children;
}

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="App">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.9" data-semver="1.4.9" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div ng-controller="AppCtrl">
        <ul>
            <li><a ng-click="updateList(0)">First kids</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-click="updateList(1)"><a ng-click="updateList(1)">Second group of kids</a>
            </li>
            <li ng-click="updateList(2)"><a ng-click="updateList(2)">Third group of kids</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="children in childrens">
                {{children.childName}}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new variable on your $scope to keep track of which children to display. Then we could create a function to update this group. See below

In your controller

```
$scope.children = $scope.adults[0]; // Default to the first group
$scope.updateGroup = function(newGroupNumber) {
    $scope.children = $scope.adults[newGroupNumber];
};
```

Then in your template:

```
<li ng-repeat="child in children>
      {{child.childName}}
</li>
...
<li ng-click="updateGroup(1)">First kids</li>
<li ng-click="updateGroup(2)">Second group of kids</li>
<li ng-click="updateGroup(3)">Third group of kids</li>
```